# How do I get a new branch to show up in Eclipse Git Remote Tracking?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have an existing Eclipse git project, with a master and development branch present in both local, and remote tracking. I have just added a new branch in my git repository, but I can't figure out how to get it to show up in Eclipse.

I have tried to read up on the subject, but it seems like it is just expected to automatically show up. I have found a lot of similar questions, but they all seem to deal with the issues of a completely empty remote tracking folder, instead of my problem of only a single new branch missing. I already have Master and Develop present.

**Here is what does not work:**

- Clicking refresh in the Git repositories window.
- Any kind of synchronize, pull or other update I can find

**Here is what would work:**

- Right clicking the remote tracking folder, and selecting "Paste repository path or URI". If I do that, and select the exact same path as is already there, I can see my new branch. This action does require that I completely clone the whole repository to an empty folder again, and that can't be how this is intended to work.
- I believe it might work to use some kind of command line tool, but I really want an Eclipse solution to this, as I feel sure it exists, and I am just missing something.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In the ***Git Repositories*** view:

1. **Right-click the repository** and choose ***Fetch from Upstream***
2. If the new branch will not shown up below *Branches/Remote Tracking*, you have to configure fetch:

   1. **Right-click the fetch node below *Remotes/origin*** and choose ***Configure Fetch...***
   2. In the *Configure Fetch* make sure there is only the single *Ref mapping* (assuming the remote is named `origin`) **`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`**:
      [image: Configure fetch]

Comment: "No ref to fetch from MyRepository - origin - everything up to date." I'll update my question with screenshots

Comment: God damnit, in my latest attempts, I just confused two different repositories. So this really does work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure that, in the URL field of the above dialog, your fork's URL is shown.

Comment: How could I configure this to all projects? I have to configure it for each project just now.
Thank you.

Comment: @Darkfalk This configuration is stored in the Git config. So I suppose without having tried it myself, in _Window > Preferences: Team > Git > Configuration_  you can copy this setting from the _Repository Settings_ tab to the _User Settings_ tab to ably it to all Git repositories.

Comment: Where is “origin” is your remote name

Comment: @lingar Yes, thanks. I added this to the answer since the remote might have a different name.

Answer (score 6):

In case you do not see ***Fetch from Upstream*** after right-click the repository, you may look for ***Fetch from origin***.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was almost what Joshua suggested, however it did not work as described. For me the solution was to configure the `[remote "origin"]` property as follows:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = your_git_url.git
    fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Alternatively, you can do it from the Eclipse UI too:

`Fetch from origin...` then hit `Configure...` and in the configuration window hit `Advanced...` and there you have the option to `Add predefined specification` where you can selec `Add All Branches Spec`. This will result in the same configuration as above:

[image: Advanced fetch configuration menu]

Maybe you have to remove your original entry which will be pointed out as a duplicate by Eclipse.

Comment: For me, this window appear this way: right click repository, "Remote->Fetch...", "Next" button

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the "config" file in your local git repository folder.  For example, you cloned a remote branch Project into c:\git\MyProject local folder.  In this folder there is a hidden folder ".git" that has a "config" file.  There is a section in this file resembling the below

[remote "origin"]
url  http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
fetch = +refs/heads/Project:refs/remotes/origin/Project

You need to modify this section as below
[remote "origin"]
url  http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Then go back to Eclipse IDE, right click on the repository and do a "fetch from origin".  Now all the branches will show up.

Answer (score -3):

What I did:
1: disconnected.
2. refresh and pull.  Then, it shows the new branch
3. create local and pull.