# How to pull a branch from remote to local in eclipse (update branch)

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

I am wondering, how to pull a branch in eclipse. I am new to Eclipse. I know that to do that i have to **pull** the remote branch, but i dont know how.

What i have tried:

1. I right clicked local and remote branch, but didnt pull there.
   [image]
2. I Right clicked on project, i found **pull** there, but it is for all branches.
   [image]
3. Also i tried to **Synchronize with Workspace**, but i didnt understand how it works

**What else can i do?**

Comment: What do you mean exactly by to pull a branch? [Show it up in the remote tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47391183/6505250), merge it with your current checked-out local branch or rebase something? Could you tell the Git command line commands or what you have and what the result should be?

Comment: I am not using git commands, only gui from eclipse. What i am trying to say is that i need somehow to updage a brunch. I am having a local branch and remote branch. How to update my local branch using Git?

Comment: Then it's just _Pull_ to do a fetch and rebase or merge the new commits from the configured remote upstream branch. In the _Git Repositories_ view, right-click the local branch and choose _Configure Branch..._ to change rebase/merge or the upstream branch. Or do _Pull..._ to get an dialog to choose the upstream branch and rebase or merge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to git too, but did you try right-clicking in your Package Explorer and trying to Fetch?

```
Team > Remote > Fetch From...
```