# How to clone a branch from a git repo with eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, gitlab

I'm a novice, who working with a git repo that have about 100 branches. I normally clone some branches that I'm using. After that, my team tell me that I should clone other branch to try something and I don't know how to clone it. Now I push all changes and deleted all local branches before clone new branches.

Sample: Git repo name is "TestRepo" and have branches [A1, A2, A3,...,A99, A100], it about 100 branches. I'm using branches A1 and A35 for a while. Team tell me to clone A99 branch. So, how to clone A99 with eclipes?

Anyway, sorry for my english and thanks for answering.

Comment: Did you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47391183/6505250

Comment: The term "clone" with respect to git only refers to repositories, not branches.  You "clone" a remote repository to your desktop.  Repositories contain branches. You "check out" particular branches from a repository.

Comment: @howlger sorry for the late reply but yes!! thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Great. So I close it as a duplicate.